# C# download pdf from ajax driven url

Tags: c#, pdf

In a C# application I would like to open a url and download a pdf.

When this url is hit from the browser the page quickly loads and begins what I believe are ajax calls.  After several seconds the browser download prompt appears with the pdf file.

I have attempted to open this url via [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  The stream I return is not the pdf file and is is the actual html of the page.

How can I detect the the pdf file has loaded and download it?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, WebClient has no clue about JavaScript, it won't run the AJAX code at all, it just gets the HTML of the page and leaves it at that.
And since likely the PDF's URL is parsed by the Javascript or the PDF is generated on demand or even streamed trough Javascript, you really need support for active content.

This seems something like Selenium would be good for. http://www.seleniumhq.org/
It'll spawn either an actual browser and steer that browser to the content you need or run the PhantomJS headless browser and fetch the content you want.

It might be a bit overkill and a more knowledgeable person might have a better answer, but that's what I've used on an application that needs to fetch PDF's, CSV's and other files from many different websites.